# Getting an undefined reference to error in c++ even though I have the functions all defined

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker

```
enum state{
state_Mmenu,    // State 0
state_settingmenu,      // State 1
state_gamemenu,     // State 2
state_savegamemenu,     // State 3
state_loadgamemenu,     // State 4;
state_Exit,         // State 5;
state_other
};

state stateMmenu();
state statesettingmenu(string, string);
state stategamemenu();
state statesavegamemenu(string, string, string, ofstream&);
state stateloadgamemenu(string, string, string, ifstream&);
state stateExit();



int main()
{
state curr=state_other;

string filename= "PlayerOne.jak";
string fname="Player";
string lname="One";
ifstream inFS;
ofstream outFS;



while(curr != state_Exit)
{
    switch(curr)
    {
        case state_Mmenu:
        curr = stateMmenu();
        break;

        case state_settingmenu:
        curr = statesettingmenu(fname, lname);
        break;

        case state_gamemenu:
        curr = stategamemenu();
        break;

        case state_savegamemenu:
        curr = statesavegamemenu(fname, lname, filename, outFS);
        break;

        case state_loadgamemenu:
        curr = stateloadgamemenu(fname, lname, filename, inFS);
        break;

        default:
            cout << "Don't Tip the Vending Machine"<<endl;
            curr = state_Mmenu;
        break;
    }
}


return 0;

 }


state statesavegamemenu(string fname, string lname, string filename, 
ofstream outFS)
{
state next=state_savegamemenu;
int choice4=0;
cout<<" -Save Game Menu-----------------"<<endl;
cout<<"1. File Name - "<<filename<<endl;
cout<<"2. Save" <<endl;
cout<<"3. Game Menu" <<endl;
cout<<"----------------------------"<<endl;
    do
{

    cout << "Choice? "<< endl;
    cin >> choice4;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(10000,'\n');

}while(!cin.good());

switch(choice4)
{
    case 1:
    {
        cout<<"What would you like to save this file as? ";
        cin>>filename;
        cout<<endl;
        next = state_savegamemenu;
    }
    break;
    case 2:
    {
        outFS.open(filename.c_str());
        if(!outFS.is_open())
        {
            next = state_savegamemenu;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            outFS<<fname<<endl;
            outFS<<lname<<endl;
        }
        outFS.close();
        next = state_savegamemenu;
    }

    break;
    case 3:
        next = state_gamemenu;
    break;
    default:
    cout << "Bad Input!"<<endl;
        next = state_savegamemenu;
    break;  
}
cout <<endl;
return next;
}

state stateloadgamemenu(string fname, string lname, string filename, 
ifstream inFS)
{
state next=state_loadgamemenu;
int choice5=0;
cout<<" -Save Game Menu-----------------"<<endl;
cout<<"1. File Name - "<<filename<<endl;
cout<<"2. Load" <<endl;
cout<<"3. Main Menu" <<endl;
cout<<"----------------------------"<<endl;
string filecontent;
    do
{

    cout << "Choice? "<< endl;
    cin >> choice5;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(10000,'\n');

}while(!cin.good());

switch(choice5)
{
    case 1:
    {
        cout<<"What file would you like to load? ";
        cin>>filename;
        cout<<endl;
        next = state_loadgamemenu;
    }
    break;
    case 2:
    {
        inFS.open(filename.c_str());
        if(!inFS.is_open())
        {
            next = state_savegamemenu;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            while(!inFS.eof())
            {
                inFS >> filecontent;
                if(inFS.good())
                {
                    cout << filecontent << endl; 
                }
            }
        }
        inFS.close();
        next = state_loadgamemenu;
    }

    break;
    case 3:
        next = state_Mmenu;
    break;
    default:
    cout << "Bad Input!"<<endl;
        next = state_loadgamemenu;
    break;  
}
cout <<endl;
return next;
}
```

The error that I'm getting is an undefined reference to statesavegamemenu(), and stateloadgamemenu(). To my knoweledge a linker error like this has to do with the program not being able to find the definition for the functions in question, but I very clearly have them implemented so I'm very confused as to why this is happening, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Might wanna trim out the code that isn't causing the error

Comment: Why can you not include the header files that might make this compilable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the save game and load game you forgot to do this so its not matching the calls

```
 state statesavegamemenu(string fname, string lname, string filename, 
ofstream outFS)
{
```

to

```
 state statesavegamemenu(string fname, string lname, string filename, 
 ofstream& outFS)
 {
```

same with the other function but ifstream instead of ifstream&

Comment: This was the issue, very much appreciated! Im so dumb

Comment: lol i've made the same mistake dozens of times id appreciate it if you checked off my answer though :)

Comment: Will do theres a minimum time limit before I can though! One quick question though, could you take a look at my statesavegame, and where i use cin>>filename, that is supposed to take a filename from the user and replace the previous one I had, but for some reason it's not overwriting it, do you see any obvious issues?

Comment: try using a c-string or char array for the filename when opening files i dont think strings work it has to be a character array so try can.getline(nameofcharacterarray,sizeofarray,delimiter)